# What does it mean to flatten an iterator?

Tags: iterator, flatten

I would like to know what it means to flatten e.g. flatten an iterator of iterators. Can you tell me? Are there any C/Java/Python idioms for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this context, to flatten means to remove nesting. For instance, an array of arrays (an array where each element is an array) of integers is nested; if we flatten it we get an array of integers which contains the same values in the same order, but next to each other in a single array, rather than split into several arrays: `[[1 2] [3 4]] -> [1 2 3 4]`. Same difference with iterators, other collections, and deeper nesting (array of array of sets of iterators of strings).

As for idioms, there aren't really many -- it's not a common task, and often simple. Note that in the case of regular arrays (all nested arrays are of the same size), `nested[i][j]` is equivalent to `nested[i * INNER_ARRAY_SIZE + j]`. This is sometimes used to avoid nesting, especially in languages which treat arrays as reference types and thus require many separately-allocated arrays if you nest them. In Python, you can flatten iterables with [`itertools.chain(*iterable_of_iterables)`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain).

Comment: -1 The standard python idiom for flattening iterables is to use `itertools.chain`.

Answer (score 2):

Flattening means to remove nesting of sequence types. Python provides `itertools.chain(*iterables)` for this purpose (http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain).